# How to create 'containers' similar to Facebook?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift

I'm creating an app that will get data from an RSS feed and I want to know how I recreate something similar to the Facebook app 'containers'

An example of what I mean is below.
[image: facebook containers]

How would I go about recreating the boxes where the statuses are held?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `UITableView` with different prototype cells and then deque the appropriate cell identifier in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to subclass `UITableView` for achieving the desired effects such as indentation etc.

After that you have to make custom view for each cell and return them from the method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your desire result you have to create custom table view cell using `UITableViewCell` and arrange views as per your need by creating subclass of `UITableViewCell`